# Чотири собаки чи п'ять собак - що за особливість?

Tags: іменники, число

Як називається ця особливість мови коли форма множини змінюється з числом?

Цікавить відмінювання іменників за числом взагалі, як один термін. Чи можливо без специфіки саме зміни відмінку, якщо в інших мовах теж є схоже явище. Щось на кшталт "множиноморфності".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follower [правий](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2714), що в будь-якому разі ця граматична категорія називається число. В різних мовах розрізняють такі значення  числа:

1. Однина.
2. Двоїна.
3. [Троїна](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0).
4. <s>Четверне число (англійською — [quadral](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number#Quadral)).</s> Виявилося помилкою, наразі жодна з відомих мов не має окремого граматичного числа для 4 предметів.
5. [Паукальне число](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE) — для декількох предметів. Деякі мови мають по декілька паукальних чисел (наприклад, «малопаукальне» для меншої кількості предметів і «великопаукальне» для більшої, наприклад, до 4 і від 4).
6. Множина.
7. Лічильна форма — коли при числівниках число виражається іншим чином, ніж без числівників.

Проблема в тому, що в сучасному українському мовознавстві не розглядають таку можливу множину значень категорії граматичного числа в українській мові як «однина (*рука́*, *1 рука́*), 2/3/4-на (*три руки́*), ≥5-на (*5 рук*) і безчислівникова множина (*ру́ки*)», хоч це було би певною мірою логічно для покриття всіх випадків. Натомість розглядають лише однину і множину (ще іноді двоїну), а форми при числівниках 2/3/4 і ≥5 називають родовим відмінком чи множиною. Це є певною мірою зрозумілим спрощенням, адже форми іменників при числівниках 2/3/4 і ≥5 справді найчастіше збігаються з родовим відмінком однини, називним відмінком множини чи родовим відмінком множини. (Але таке спрощення не є повністю логічним і через нього виникають інші питання.)

Як назвати одним словом те, що:

- з точки зору категорій сучасного українського мовознавства ми при деяких числівниках маємо використовувати родовий відмінок замість називного

— або те, що:

- залишки старих граматичних систем призводять до того, що форми при числівниках не вписуються до кінця навіть в ці категорії

— або те, що:

- з точки зору носія іншої мови може виглядати так, що ми маємо не однину і множину (і частково двоїну), а як мінімум «однину», «2/3/4-ну», «≥5-ну» і «звичайну (безчислівникову) множину»

— я, на жаль, не знаю.

Декількома словами я би охарактеризував це як «складна система чисел // на залишках старих систем // що з точки зору іноземця може виглядати так, наче в нас більше категорій граматичного числа, ніж однина/множина(/двоїна)».

Comment: Дякую. Паукальне число - це саме той термін що мене цікавить.
Ось що я знайшов з вашою допомогою в англійській  Вікіпедії: 
```
In Russian, a form similar to genitive singular (the remnants of the dual number[citation needed]) is also applied to three or four items (2, 3, 4 ка́мня – stones, gen. sg.; but 5...20 камне́й - stones, gen. pl.), making it effectively paucal (cf. э́тот ка́мень - this stone, nom. sg.; э́ти ка́мни - these stones, nom. pl.).

Comment: @hutorny, так, це саме те, що я хотів сказати. Що з точки зору міжнародної лінгвістики оці «дві сестри́» і «п'ять сестер» можна було б розглядати не як родові відмінки, а як окремі числа (можливо, малопаукальне і великопаукальне; чи, вірніше, паукальне і спеціальна лічильна форма множини). Мабуть, так було б логічніше, але в нас так не прийнято.

Answer (score 5):

Загальна особливість мови

> [Число](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)) — ґраматична категорія, що вказує на кількість предметів,
>   про які ся мовить в реченнї.

Підзагальностї

> [Однина](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) — форма числа у мовознавстві, яка в іменниках означає один предмет серед однорідних.
>
> ---
>
> [Множина](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)) — в мовознавстві форма числа. У більшостї сучасних индоєвропейських мов множина протиставляється однині.

Бува мали таке чи маємо лише в деяких говірках

> [Двоїна](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0) — ґраматична категорія числа, яку вживають, щоб позначити дві особи чи парні предмети.

---

Але, вважаю, суть сьому взагалї в иншому, а саме в **історічній успадкованостї**.

**Чотири**, **пʼять** — [числівники](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA). Але в давнину:

- Числівники були лише [семантикою](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)
- Ґраматично слова *одинъ, дъва, триє, четыре* були [прикметниками](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)
- А слова для позначення чисел від *5* були вже [іменниками](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)

І таким чином [ся відмінювало](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA).

---

[До речі](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/228.htm), що якщо числівник стоїть після іменника в родовому відмінку — *собак три*, то се буде вказувати на неточність, себто допущення чи на штиб цього.

Також наголошу, що це (*примітка:* можлива хибність лоґіки) не

> [Паукальне число](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE) — ґраматична категорія іменника, прикметника, займенників-іменників і займенників-прикметників, що означає, що ця частина мови вказує на декілька предметів або осіб.

Оскільки подїбна структура відмінювань зберігається і для складених числівниках: *двадцять чотири собаки, але двадцять пʼять собак*.

Comment: «Це не паукальне число…, оскільки подїбна структура відмінювань зберігається і для складених числівників» — по-моєму, не аргумент. Із таким же успіхом ми можемо сказати, що «двацять одна (чи сто одна) сестра́» — не однина (бо сестер ажно 21 (101), а не 1). Просто в нас така граматика, що форми при числівниках _10m+n_ повторюють форми при числівниках _n_ (за винятком випадків, коли _m mod 10=1_).

Comment: Я мав на увазі, що не бачу логіки в твердженні «„4 сестри“ — не паукальне число, бо „24 сестри“ мають ту ж форму». Із таким же успіхом можна сказати «„1 сестра“ — не однина, бо „21 сестра“ має ту ж форму». Десь же треба зупинитися.

Comment: НМД, в першу чергу важливо _які_ категорії виділяти, а не як їх називати. І якщо вважати (застаріле і діалектне) «дві руці» нормативним, то окрему двоїну таки маємо. (Адже можна сказати «2/3/4 руки́» і за великим бажанням «2 руці».)

Comment: [Тут](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0#.D0.A5.D0.86.D0.A5_.D1.81.D1.82..C2.A0.E2.80.94_.D0.A5.D0.A5_.D1.81.D1.82.) згадують ся, що можна було і «за бажанням» _3, 4 руці_. Тотожні категорії?

Comment: Ясно. Ну тоді справді маємо дві альтернативні форми паукального числа (більш нормативну/сучасну і більш діалектну/застарілу). (Хоча не факт, що вони повністю тотожні. Можливо, все-таки при різних числівниках перевага різним формам надавалась або була різниця в конотації — принаймні в частині діалектів.)

Comment: Чи одна давня форма ся перетворила в застарілу двоїну, а друга сі зберегла. Тому давно вони могли бути тотожними, але пізнїше — вже нї, ось тут і конотацїї. Тема взагалї непростенькою виходить.